# Query runs in phpmyadmin but not through application

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi im having an interesting problem.

**Update:** From the comments im getting below this seems to be an issue of trying to run multiple queries at the same time. I had assumed that since I was doing it in phpmyadmin, then it was all good. How does one go about running multiple queries? I am using mysqli? I am using mysql 5.x and using mysqli

Im running my query from my application and if the query does not function I echo it to the screen. Along with is's error

When i run my application I get my query printed to the screen and this error.

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE tmp_bulletins ADD INDEX (`bb_id`); ' at line 13**

When I copy the query which was echoed to the screen and run it in phpmyadmin it works fine every time. I have then tried taking the query that was echoed to the screen and running that on the database through my application and it doesn't work.

As far as I can tell, the exact same query(the one printed to my screen) is working through phpmyadmin, but not through my applcation.

Is there any reason that this might happen? Does phpmyadmin make some changes to a query before it runs it on the database?

Here is the query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_bulletins

                   SELECT {$table}.id AS bb_id,count(bb_replies.id) AS num_responses,bb_locations.title AS location,bb_locations.description AS location_description,bb_categories.title AS category,bb_categories.description AS category_description,Concat(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name) AS full_name,users.first_name AS first_name,users.last_name as last_name,users.id AS user_id,{$table}.title AS post_title,{$table}.content,{$table}.created_date,{$table}.rank 
                   FROM `{$table}` 
                   LEFT JOIN bb_locations ON {$table}.bb_locations_id = bb_locations.id
                   LEFT JOIN bb_categories ON {$table}.bb_categories_id = bb_categories.id
                   LEFT JOIN users ON {$table}.users_id = users.id
                   LEFT JOIN bb_replies ON {$table}.id = bb_replies.bbs_id
                   WHERE `bb_locations_id` IN ({$locations_csv}) AND `bb_categories_id` IN ({$categories_csv}) {$addWhere}
                   GROUP BY bb_id,location,location_description,category,category_description,first_name,last_name,user_id,post_title,content,created_date,rank
                   {$order} {$limit} ;

              ALTER TABLE tmp_bulletins ADD INDEX (`bb_id`);


              CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_ratings      

                   SELECT bbs_id,
                   sum(CASE WHEN user_id = {$user_id} THEN like_dislike_id END) AS thisUsersRating,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN like_dislike_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes, 
                   SUM(CASE WHEN like_dislike_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dislikes
                   FROM bb_ratings
                   GROUP BY bbs_id;  

              ALTER TABLE tmp_ratings ADD INDEX (`bbs_id`); 

              SELECT * FROM tmp_bulletins
          LEFT JOIN tmp_ratings on tmp_bulletins.bb_id = tmp_ratings.bbs_id;
```

And the query that it produces(editing the look as we speak)

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_bulletins 
    SELECT bbs.id AS bb_id,count(bb_replies.id) AS num_responses, 
    bb_locations.title AS
     location,bb_locations.description AS location_description,
    bb_categories.title AS
     category,bb_categories.description AS category_description,
    Concat(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name) AS full_name,
    users.first_name AS first_name,
    users.last_name as last_name,users.id AS user_id,
    bbs.title AS post_title,
    bbs.content,bbs.created_date,bbs.rank FROM `bbs` 
    LEFT JOIN bb_locations ON bbs.bb_locations_id = bb_locations.id 
    LEFT JOIN bb_categories ON bbs.bb_categories_id = bb_categories.id 
    LEFT JOIN users ON bbs.users_id = users.id LEFT JOIN bb_replies ON bbs.id = bb_replies.bbs_id WHERE `bb_locations_id` IN (1,2) AND `bb_categories_id` IN (1,2) 
    GROUP BY bb_id,location,location_description,category,category_description,first_name,last_name,user_id,post_title,content,created_date,rank LIMIT 0,5; ALTER TABLE tmp_bulletins 
    ADD INDEX (`bb_id`); 

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_ratings 
    SELECT bbs_id, sum(CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN like_dislike_id END) AS thisUsersRating, SUM(CASE WHEN like_dislike_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN like_dislike_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dislikes FROM bb_ratings GROUP BY bbs_id; 
ALTER TABLE tmp_ratings ADD INDEX (`bbs_id`); 

    SELECT * FROM tmp_bulletins LEFT JOIN tmp_ratings on tmp_bulletins.bb_id = tmp_ratings.bbs_id
```

Comment: How about posting the actual query?

Comment: Ok so I need I need to user multi_query? this is all very new to me, I have never run more than one query at a time. Would that be causing the problem?

Comment: PHP's mysql driver does not allow multiple query commands to be executed with a single `...query()` call as a security measure against some forms of SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

are you executing multiple queries at once?

**EDIT**

Your queries are complex, simplify it and run query by query. To identify the problem.

Comment: Yes I am and I am using mysqli

Comment: Is there a way to send multiple queries when you are using mysqli, bear with me im still getting my head around mysqli and database queries

Comment: make sure you are not missing any step  http://www.suite101.com/content/how-tor-run-multiple-mysql-queries-with-php-a105672

Comment: what I don't understand is that PMA has no problems running multiple queries. How does it do it and how should I do it?

Comment: the difference is phpmyadmin runs it query by query

Comment: I don't think it is the complexity of the query that is the problem, it's the fact that I am running the query in the incorrect way. I know that this query works because when I put it into phpmyadmin it returns the desired result, I think the issue might be that I am using query. I have only just learned that there is such a thing as  multi_query though I am still not sure whether or not this will be the solution

Answer (score 2):

Take out the semicolon.

Comment: which semi-colon, how will that help? why does make a difference when running it through phpmyadmin or through my application?

Comment: You don't give any detail and you assume that I will know what you are talking about.

Comment: As the other commenters noted, you need to enable multi query, or send your commands as multiple queries, or use a stored procedure. PHPMyAdmin presumably can split up the queries or properly use a multi query, while you did not.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could show the whole query.

Do you use multi-queries? If yes, this will work in PMA, but without PMA it depends on mysql-version and -settings, if it could work.

Comment: yes im storing the first two queries in temp tables and then running a query on those two

Comment: but I am running the query on the same database. I installed xampp so shouldn't PMA and my application run the queries in the same way? If not what changes do I need to make to my application?

Comment: No, PMA may split it and execute separate queries or use mysqli_multi_query(), what could be an option to you too.